# Create a struct by reflection in Go

Tags: go

I want to define a struct completely dynamically, so that I can get the following struct, but without defining it first?

```
type Data struct {
   a string
   b int `json:"b"`
}
d := Data{}
```

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: The main issue here is that you cannot, via reflection, *set* any unexported field (since Go 1.8). Since `a` and `b` are both unexported, you will only be able to create a zero-valued `Data` object.

Comment: Yes you can create structs via reflection.

Comment: The function https://godoc.org/reflect#StructOf will get you most of the way there.  The unexported fields shown in the question are not supported.

Comment: I'm with @bereal here, why is this needed? There might be another way that doesn't rely on reflection and etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An application can create a struct programmatically using [reflect.StructOf](https://godoc.org/reflect#StructOf), but all fields in the struct must be [exported](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers).

The question gets the struct as a value, but it's likely that a pointer to the struct is more useful to the application.

Given the above, this answer shows how to do the following without defining the type at compile time:

```
type Data struct {
   A string `json:"a"`
   B int `json:"b"`
}
var d interface{} = &Data{}
```

The code is:

```
t := reflect.StructOf([]reflect.StructField{
    {
        Name: "A",
        Type: reflect.TypeOf(int(0)),
        Tag:  `json:"a"`,
    },
    {
        Name: "B",
        Type: reflect.TypeOf(""),
        Tag:  `json:"B"`,
    },
})
d := reflect.New(t).Interface()
```

Here's a runnable example that sets some fields: https://play.golang.org/p/uik7Ph8_BRH